# WINERROR 32 when deleting a PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, zip, pypdf

I'm making a program that unzips a zip file that has pdf's, joins them into one and at the end deletes the files except the one that was created.
But I get `PermissionError:[WinError 32] The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process`

Here's my code:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\kovac\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages")

import re, glob, zipfile
from os.path import isfile, join
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
from os import listdir, chdir, getcwd, remove

onlyfiles = []
onlyzip = []

# dir in the root
os.chdir("asdfghjkl")

# get all the zip files
for file in glob.glob("*.zip"):
    onlyzip += [file]

# unzip all the zip files
for x in onlyzip:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(x, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall()
        zip_ref.close()

# get all the PDF
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    onlyfiles += [file]

merger = PdfFileMerger()

# print for better view of whats happening
print(f"merging {len(onlyfiles)} files from {len(onlyzip)} zip ({onlyzip}):")
for x in onlyfiles:
    print(f"- {x}")

# merge all th files into a new one 'PDF_MERGED.pdf'
for x in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(onlyfiles[x], 'rb')))
merger.write(f"PDF_MERGED.pdf")
merger.close() # Here i thought that could solve the problem but it didn't

# delete all the zip files     it works
for file in onlyzip:
    os.remove(file)

# delete all the pdf files form the list [onlyfiles], it excludes the 'PDF_merged.pdf' file
for file in onlyfiles:
    os.remove(file) # here causes trouble


print("Finished!")
```

I thought that `zipfile.close()` and `merger.close()` whould help, it does with the zip file, but not the pdf. Some ideas in how to solve this?

Comment: `merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(onlyfiles[x], 'rb')))` You're calling `open()` on each onlyfile, but then you never close it.

Comment: The line `merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(onlyfiles[x], 'rb')))` calls "open" but does not explicitly close the returned file object.

Comment: Just give PyPDF2 the file name. Don't call open

Comment: Also: you're using deprecated classes from PyPDF2